# How to solve "The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded" error in WCF?

Tags: wcf

Even though I set all values to 2147483647

```
Client side :

 <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPortfolioBALService" 
        closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"  
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas 
                 maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
             maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                 maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">

    Server side:

    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPortfolioDALService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
              openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
              allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
              maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
              messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
              useDefaultWebProxy="true">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                  realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
```

I am getting the error. I wanted to get 168 records from database to a list. But I am getting this error. Please tell me where to change.

**I am getting the  error1 while saving an image of size more than 16KB.Is there any thing to change to save image.**
error1:
The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 34042.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: And are you actually **using** this binding configuration?? Did you do this both on the server and the client??

Comment: Yes marc...I got the same error in saving Image of size more than 16kB     i didn't find required solution.please help me.

Comment: Can you post the full WCF config (anything inside your `<system.serviceModel>` for both the server and the client side??

Comment: You need to set also <system.web><httpRuntime maxRequestLength="<your length>" /></system.web>.  Note also a common mistake in your service definition, if there is a mismatch between the contract namespace in your web.config and the code, .Net 4 will use default settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set values for MaxReceivedMessageSize,maxArrayLength, maxStringContentLength, maxBufferSize on both Servers web.config and Client config file. Also make sure that your HttpRunTime element have the maxRequestLength set.

Comment: Thank you Rajesh...it solved my requirement to get all data from Database,Please tell me how to save Image of size more than 16KB in to Database through WCF.